# Stackexchange vs Personal Blog - Pagerank Competition

Tags: seo

As you can see I'm using my real name on every StackExchange site including stackoverflow.com.

Given an unspecific time period, is it possible for my very own personal blog to compete with any StackExchange Site? I really like my personal blog to be page rank one and don't have to change my name i.e. on Stackoverflow.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a link to your personal blog from your user profile - this link will be marked up with the "me" relationship and should contribute to an improved ranking for your personal site when people search for information about you.

It wouldn't hurt to develop other links to your personal site, as well - consider creating a [Google Profile](http://www.google.com/profiles).

Answer (score 2):

And when you have a certain rank, the link in your profile to your blog will no longer be marked as nofollow.

Comment: +1 Good point there - I figured that Henrik's rep of 6275 @ StackOverflow would be sufficient, though he'd have to stick around a while to see similar effect here @ Pro Webmasters

Comment: FYI: The hard limit for a non-nonfollow ref is 2000 reputation

Answer (score 1):

Profile pages in themselves don't tend to carry much weight so you should be able to outrank them all with your personal blog pretty quickly. I looked through the first few pages of results and only saw profile listings. Beyond linking all of these profiles to your blog and getting other links you may want to look at the content of your blog, often using your name as the domain gives you an exact match domain which will help you rank, but you'll also want to make sure there is content using your name on the site so the search engines will know it's about you. (This sounds like common sense but you'd be surprised how many people have sites about themselves and never use their name once in the content).

Answer (score 1):

My personal site outranks every other profile I have on the Web including SO. So the answer to your question is yes.